# c++ and c# COM interop,doesn't work from two different machines

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I am trying to have a link between my c# and c++ projects. The project gives me a perfect output.  C# code is generating a tlb which I am importing inside by c++ project. Now i want to take my tlb,c# dll, c++ dll and c++ lib into other system and execute my code. Its not giving any particular error but i have realized that the part of c# code in my c++ code is not getting excuted. The solution gets stuck.
How can we take the tbl and all the dll in make them work?
I am trying this out for the first time. I need help

Comment: Is that COM object being registered on the other system? IIRC C# COM objects require the use of regasm to register their COM objects.

Comment: how can we register the c# COM objects?

Comment: Could it be a x64/x86 problem?

Comment: no i guess. Both are build with x86 in release mode

Comment: try registering the dll with `regasm xxx.dll /codebase`

Comment: thanks a lot @ZdeslavVojkovic & NialI ...its working.